# Count tabs per line and return the lines with too many tabs

Tags: powershell, count

Looking for a PowerShell script that looks in a text file for rows that have too many (or too few) tabs.

I found this PowerShell script that does exactly what I want (almost).

This counts the number of tabs per row:

```
Get-Content test.txt | ForEach-Object { 
    ($_ | Select-String `t -all).matches | Measure-Object | Select-Object count
}
```

Can someone extend/modify/re-write this to return only the rows (with row numbers) that have more than, or less than, X number of tabs per row?

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `Get-Content` before piping to `Select-String`, you'll lose contextual information about each line.

Instead, use the `-Path` parameter with `Select-String`:

```
$Tabs = Select-String -Path .\test.txt -Pattern "`t" -AllMatches 
$Tabs |Select-Object LineNumber,Line,@{Name='TabCount';Expression={ $_.Matches.Count }}
```

To return only the ones where the number of tabs is greater than `$x`, use `Where-Object`:

```
$x = 3
$Tabs |Where-Object { $_.TabCount -ge $x} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line
```

---

If you just want a quick overview of the distribution, you could also use `Group-Object`:

```
Get-Content .\test.txt | Group-Object { "{0} tabs" -f [regex]::Matches($_,"`t").Count }
```

Comment: You, sir, are awesome! You nailed it!

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do this. `Get-Content` works just fine for me and we create a custom object that you can then filter as desired.

```
Get-Content test.txt | ForEach-Object{
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Line = $_
        LineNumber = $_.ReadCount
        NumberofTabs =  [regex]::matches($_,"`t").count
    }
}
```

Use the .net regex method to count the tabs returned and populate a value based on the result.

```
NumberofTabs Number Line                                            
------------ ------ ----                                            
           8      1                 ;lkjasfdsa                      
           8      2                         asdfasdf                
           4      3          asdfasdfasdfa                          
           2      4  fasdfjasdlfjas;l
```

Now you can use PowerShell to filter as you see fit.

```
} | Where-Object { $_.NumberofTabs -ne 4}
```

So if 4 was the perfect number then line 3 would be ommited from the results.